# How can I do a drag action in HTML5 with right mouse button?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I know that HTML5 can do a drag action with left mouse button.
But, is it possible to perform a drag action with right mouse button instead of left mouse button?

I'm using [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop):

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag the image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="http://lorempixel.com/336/69/abstract/4/" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

Comment: According to MDN, the `button` property of the [`drag` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag) describes which mouse button was pressed: "Left button=0, middle button=1 (if present), right button=2". Can you show us the code you've got so far and what specifically is going wrong?

Comment: [OnlineExample](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop)     this is the online example I want to modify,but I don't how to drag the item using right mouse button instead of left mouse button.